# Will Angular treeshake a service that is provided in root as long as it is not injected into a component instance?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If we have a service like this that is part of a library:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ChartJSProvider {
  constructor() {
    Chart.register(...registerables);
  }
}
```

And an app that uses the library.

Will the `ChartJSProvider` singleton automatically be created by and be included in running instances of the Angular application even if it is not injected into any component that the app uses, or does it get tree shaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason `{ providedIn: 'root' }` was introduced was to allow easy tree shaking of unused services.

At compiler time it just setups the factory that it used by the DI system.

So, if it's not injected (via `inject()` or constructor injection), yes the class will removed from the bundle by the tree-shaking optimization.